# BS4 Python: Trying to take page links from Google but the URLs I get are all the same

Tags: python, html, google-chrome, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have made a python script with BS4 to try to get the results from a google search.

**Problem:** I can only take data from Page 1 of Google

**Attempt to Solve:** I tried to extract each pages href at the bottom of google [page list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4lS6.png) and get the href for each page from 1,2,3...10 and repeat my process as I did for page 1.

**Problem to attempt:** When I tried to extract pages 1..10 URL those page links are not the same as the ones in the inspect element on google.com .
[google inspect element links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/km6nb.png)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import functions
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
url = 'https://google.com/search?q=manga'  # main link to get data
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0'}  # headers
source = requests.get(url,headers = headers).text  # url source

#making tasty soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------

pages = []


search_div = soup.find_all(class_='rc')  # find all divs    tha contains search result

def get_result(search):
    result = []
    for result in search:  # loop result list
        print('Title: %s' % result.h3.string)  # geting h3
        result.append(result.h3.string)

        print('Url: %s' % result.a.get('href'))  # geting a.href

        print('Description: %s' % result.find(class_='st').text)  # description
        print('\n###############\n')

    return result
result = get_result(search_div)

a = soup.find('table')
b = soup.find("tr", {'valign':'top'})

for i in b:
    print(str(i))
```

edit:
the code above produces:

```
Title: Manga - Wikipedia
Url: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manga
Description: Manga are comics or graphic novels originating from Japan. Most manga conform to a style developed in Japan in the late 19th century, though the art form has ...

###############

Title: Read the Best Manga - VIZ
Url: https://www.viz.com/read
Description: Action, adventure, fantasy, mystery, romance and more—thousands of manga volumes for every fan!

###############

Title: Manga Toon - Free manga, comic and novel reader online
Url: https://mangatoon.mobi/
Description: MangaToon is a Global APP for Reading Comic Manga and Novel. Different comics in Action, Romance, Boys' love, Comedy, Horror and more are updated ...

###############

Title: Read Popular Manga Online - Crunchyroll
Url: https://www.crunchyroll.com/comics/manga
Description: Read your favorite Japanese manga online on Crunchyroll including Attack on Titan, Fairy Tail, The Seven Deadly Sins, Fuuka, Knight's & Magic, and more.

###############

Title: Manga Books - Goodreads
Url: https://www.goodreads.com/genres/manga
Description: Manga. Japanese or Japanese-influenced comics and graphic novels. Usually printed in black-and-white. There are many genres inside manga, the most distinct being shojo (for girls) and shonen (for boys).

###############

Title: Manga and Anime Books | Barnes & Noble®
Url: https://www.barnesandnoble.com/b/books/graphic-novels-comics/manga/_/N-29Z8q8Zucc
Description: Discover an extensive collection of manga and anime books at Barnes & Noble. Shop a wide variety of Manga series, boxed sets, bestsellers, and more.

###############

Title: 50 Best Manga You Must Read Right Now: Classics And New ...
Url: https://bookriot.com/2020/05/26/best-manga/
Description: May 26, 2020 - New to reading manga and don't know where to start? Want to find a new series to dive into? Here's a list of the 50 best manga to add to your ...

###############

Title: MANGA Plus
Url: https://mangaplus.shueisha.co.jp/updates
Description: "MANGA Plus by SHUEISHA" is the official manga reader from Shueisha Inc., and is available globally. We publish the greatest manga in the world such as ...

###############

<td class="b d6cvqb"><span class="SJajHc" style="background:url(/images/nav_logo299.png) no-repeat;background-position:-24px 0;width:28px"></span></td>
<td class="YyVfkd"><span class="SJajHc" style="background:url(/images/nav_logo299.png) no-repeat;background-position:-53px 0;width:20px"></span>1</td>
<td><a aria-label="Page 2" class="fl" href="/search?q=manga&amp;ei=E5r7XviHIMbn-QbH4b0Y&amp;start=10&amp;sa=N&amp;ved=2ahUKEwi43ZGeqqrqAhXGc94KHcdwDwMQ8tMDegQIExAs"><span class="SJajHc NVbCr" style="background:url(/images/nav_logo299.png) no-repeat;background-position:-74px 0;width:20px"></span>2</a></td>
<td><a aria-label="Page 3" class="fl" href="/search?q=manga&amp;ei=E5r7XviHIMbn-QbH4b0Y&amp;start=20&amp;sa=N&amp;ved=2ahUKEwi43ZGeqqrqAhXGc94KHcdwDwMQ8tMDegQIExAu"><span class="SJajHc NVbCr" style="background:url(/images/nav_logo299.png) no-repeat;background-position:-74px 0;width:20px"></span>3</a></td>
<td><a aria-label="Page 4" class="fl" href="/search?q=manga&amp;ei=E5r7XviHIMbn-QbH4b0Y&amp;start=30&amp;sa=N&amp;ved=2ahUKEwi43ZGeqqrqAhXGc94KHcdwDwMQ8tMDegQIExAw"><span class="SJajHc NVbCr" style="background:url(/images/nav_logo299.png) no-repeat;background-position:-74px 0;width:20px"></span>4</a></td>
<td><a aria-label="Page 5" class="fl" href="/search?q=manga&amp;ei=E5r7XviHIMbn-QbH4b0Y&amp;start=40&amp;sa=N&amp;ved=2ahUKEwi43ZGeqqrqAhXGc94KHcdwDwMQ8tMDegQIExAy"><span class="SJajHc NVbCr" style="background:url(/images/nav_logo299.png) no-repeat;background-position:-74px 0;width:20px"></span>5</a></td>
<td><a aria-label="Page 6" class="fl" href="/search?q=manga&amp;ei=E5r7XviHIMbn-QbH4b0Y&amp;start=50&amp;sa=N&amp;ved=2ahUKEwi43ZGeqqrqAhXGc94KHcdwDwMQ8tMDegQIExA0"><span class="SJajHc NVbCr" style="background:url(/images/nav_logo299.png) no-repeat;background-position:-74px 0;width:20px"></span>6</a></td>
<td><a aria-label="Page 7" class="fl" href="/search?q=manga&amp;ei=E5r7XviHIMbn-QbH4b0Y&amp;start=60&amp;sa=N&amp;ved=2ahUKEwi43ZGeqqrqAhXGc94KHcdwDwMQ8tMDegQIExA2"><span class="SJajHc NVbCr" style="background:url(/images/nav_logo299.png) no-repeat;background-position:-74px 0;width:20px"></span>7</a></td>
<td><a aria-label="Page 8" class="fl" href="/search?q=manga&amp;ei=E5r7XviHIMbn-QbH4b0Y&amp;start=70&amp;sa=N&amp;ved=2ahUKEwi43ZGeqqrqAhXGc94KHcdwDwMQ8tMDegQIExA4"><span class="SJajHc NVbCr" style="background:url(/images/nav_logo299.png) no-repeat;background-position:-74px 0;width:20px"></span>8</a></td>
<td><a aria-label="Page 9" class="fl" href="/search?q=manga&amp;ei=E5r7XviHIMbn-QbH4b0Y&amp;start=80&amp;sa=N&amp;ved=2ahUKEwi43ZGeqqrqAhXGc94KHcdwDwMQ8tMDegQIExA6"><span class="SJajHc NVbCr" style="background:url(/images/nav_logo299.png) no-repeat;background-position:-74px 0;width:20px"></span>9</a></td>
<td><a aria-label="Page 10" class="fl" href="/search?q=manga&amp;ei=E5r7XviHIMbn-QbH4b0Y&amp;start=90&amp;sa=N&amp;ved=2ahUKEwi43ZGeqqrqAhXGc94KHcdwDwMQ8tMDegQIExA8"><span class="SJajHc NVbCr" style="background:url(/images/nav_logo299.png) no-repeat;background-position:-74px 0;width:20px"></span>10</a></td>
<td aria-level="3" class="b d6cvqb" role="heading"><a class="G0iuSb" href="/search?q=manga&amp;ei=E5r7XviHIMbn-QbH4b0Y&amp;start=10&amp;sa=N&amp;ved=2ahUKEwi43ZGeqqrqAhXGc94KHcdwDwMQ8NMDegQIExA-" id="pnnext" style="text-align:left"><span class="SJajHc NVbCr" style="background:url(/images/nav_logo299.png) no-repeat;background-position:-96px 0;width:71px"></span><span style="display:block;margin-left:53px">Next</span></a></td>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

How I tested if the links were correct: I went into my search bar on chrome and entered "google.com" to see if the page number changed. I tried each link and I am always on the first page.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]? Some minimal content which should work but doesn't, and an explanation of what you think it should do, and what it actually does. I imagine the contents of `source` are not what you think they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script prints all headers from google page and then tries to find next `<a>` link (link that contains word "Next"). If the link is found, continue loading the next page:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://google.com/search?q=manga&hl=en'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0'}

page = 1
while True:
    print()
    print('Page {}...'.format(page))
    print('-' * 80)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')
    for h in soup.select('h3'):
        print(h.get_text(strip=True))

    next_link = soup.select_one('a:contains("Next")')
    if not next_link:
        break

    url = 'https://google.com' + next_link['href']
    page += 1
```

Prints:

```
Page 1...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Manga - Wikipedia
Read the Best Manga - VIZ
Manga Toon - Free manga, comic and novel reader online
Read Popular Manga Online - Crunchyroll
Manga Books - Goodreads
MANGA Plus
Videos
MANGA Plus by SHUEISHA - Apps on Google Play
MANGA.CLUB｜Read Free Official Manga Online!
50 Best Manga You Must Read Right Now: Classics And New ...
Images

Page 2...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Top 10 Best Manga Series - YouTube
What are Manga and Anime - MIT
manga - Wiktionary
15 Best Manga Of All Time (According To MyAnimeList) | CBR
Images for manga
Guided Search Filters
Manga Storm on the App Store
A Beginner's Guide to Manga | The New York Public Library
Manga and Anime Books | Barnes & Noble®
Manga | Definition of Manga by Merriam-Webster
Manga Rock - Online Manga Reader

Page 3...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
manga - Urban Dictionary

...and so on.
```